# Insert results of a query as a new column into the table you are querying

Tags: sql, concatenation, calculated-columns

I'm experienced with MySql, but a Sql Server newbie... I'm attempting to insert a concatenated string column into the same table I'm querying. This is probably something simple, I think I have the complicated part in the query, I just can't figure out how to simply insert it into the table as a new column.

I've basically just tried insert into TABLE, which gives me the error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. I've also tried creating the column w/ NULL values, then inserting as (basically using "set" like in mysql).

Here is the query I'm running to get the concatenated column.

```
select ID_Column,
STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + StuffToConcat_Column))
From Table As T1
Where (T1.ID_Column = T2.ID_Column)
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM TABLE as T2
Group by ID_Column;
```

I'd like to just tack this on to the same table as a new column... Bonus question, If there are more than two values being added up per ID, would I need more than the: FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') line (i.e., if one of the IDs had more than 2 distinct values in StuffToConcat columns)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

> "Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column name or number of supplied
>   values does not match table definition."

I have tried a few other things now, each with different error messages:

```
 Update dbo.Table
 set dbo.Table.NewVariable = 
 (select ID_column, STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + StuffToConcat_Column
 From dbo.Table As T1
 Where (T1.ID_Column = T2.ID_Column)
 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS NewVariable
 FROM dbo.Table as T2
 Group by ID_Column);
```

Which returns: "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

I've also tried:

```
 Update dbo.Table
 set dbo.Table.NewVariable = 
 (STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + StuffToConcat_Column
 From dbo.Table As T1
 Where (T1.ID_Column = T2.ID_Column)
 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS NewVariable
 FROM dbo.Table as T2
 Group by ID_Column);
```

Which returns: "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Here is requested sample data and outcome:

---

ID Column       StuffToConcat_Column       NewVariable (Outcome)
1                       Black                Black
2                       Red                  Red, Blue,
2                       Blue                 Red, Blue,
3                       Purple               Purple, Yellow, Orange,
3                       Yellow               Purple, Yellow, Orange,
3                       Orange               Purple, Yellow, Orange,

---

---

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain why you would be storing a comma-delimited list in a string column.  That seems like a really bad thing to do.

Comment: FYI:  If you have a recent version of SQL Server (>= 2017) you can use [`string-agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I could change the delimiter, I guess... It doesn't really matter, there aren't any other commas in this data (for that field). I just want to create a column that contains all possible (unique) words for a given ID. There are duplicate IDs and the other field has unique information.

Comment: String-agg returns an error saying that it's not a known function (or something similar to that), so I don't think I have it.